# Unity - How to export equipment properly from Blender?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, asset-management

I'm trying to work out the Blender-to-Unity workflow for equipable items. At the moment, I've got a character animated for running, idling, jumping, etc. Now, I want to add equipment for him. I watched some tutorials and set up equipment in Blender with an offset bone that doesn't deform. I also parented the sword to that bone. This is working in Blender with the animations correctly moving the sword.

Then, I bring in the model and armature for the character model as an FBX, set up again the animations; separately, I bring in the sword with the rig as per the tutorial I've watched. When I set it as a child of the parent GameObject for the character model, the sword aligns itself to the right position. However, when the character animates, the sword doesn't move integrally with the hands.

How do I get this up and running? In the tutorial, it worked just by setting it as a child.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the sword with no animations, and simply parenting it to the character's hand bone transform inside Unity?

Comment: Is this good practice? the videos I've been watching don't seem to follow this procedure?

Comment: My general gamedev approach is to focus on what works and what doesn't, rather than what anyone else is doing. So: I'm curious whether this works for your use case or not.

Comment: O for sure! I'm just trying to build good habits while I'm learning, so curious if there's a robust way to handle this, so that I don't hit any hiccups along the way :) thanks for your help!